# Classic ASP passing value between pages

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

On loading of page A.asp default case is getting executed and from there the case of Email is getting executed and in case of Email we are calling Page B. I want to execute the same case of email when the control is being transferred from Page B to page A. Please help me on the same.

```
Page A 
<%@ Language=JavaScript%>
<% if (String(Request("op")) != "undefined")
var op = String(Request("op"));
%>
<%
switch (op) {
case ("EMAIL"):
Response.write("<form id = 'Upload1' name ='Upload' method ='Post' action ='B.asp?op=DocAuthors’ enctype=’multipart/form-data’> \n”);
break;
default:
Response.write("<form name=campaignCreator action=A.asp method=POST> 
Response.write("<input type=hidden name=op value=Email>
<input type=submit value='EMAILDOC'>}
Page B 
<% @ Language= VBScript%> 

Response.redirect("A.asp?op=Email " )
%>
```

I tried to pass the value through query string but still it is loading the default case not executing the case of Email.

```
Page B 
<% @ Language= VBScript%> 

Response.redirect("A.asp?op=Email " )
```

Is there anyway by which i can execute the case of email after executing page B.

Answer (score 2):

String comparisons are case sensitive.

```
Response.redirect("A.asp?op=Email " )
```

You are passing the value `Email` in your querystring, but in your case statement you are looking for `EMAIL` (note difference in upper/lower case).

```
case ("EMAIL"):
```

Try changing one or the other.

Comment: I always pefer to do string comparisons case insensitively something like `Select Case UCase(op)` in the OPs example.